# iOS Swift: Dismiss View Controller That Was Presented Using "Show Detail"

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view controller that is embedded in a navigation controller. I use show detail in storyboard to show it. How would I dismiss this view controller or go back to previous one?

I know back functionality comes automatically when using "Show Detail" but I need to embed this one in a navigation controller, which doesn't allow the back functionality, so I needed to put a "Cancel" bar button, but It's not working. I tried these ways but didn't work:

```
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: So you are using a split view controller? What would happen on say, an iPad? On an iPad you can't hide the detail view can you?

Comment: Yes I'm, on the iPad it makes sense for it not to get dismissed, but the same app should work on iPhones too with expected behaviors.

Comment: Have you tried an unwind segue?

Comment: Yea it worked! I thought about it but wanted to see if there are ways to dismiss this view controller. I think this is the correct way to do it, you can add it as an answer so I accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an unwind segue from the detail controller to the master controller.

In your master controller, add a method that handles the unwind action:

```
@IBAction func unwindFromDetail(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

Then in the storyboard, control drag from detail controller to the "Exit" of master controller, then select the above method.

Give the segue an identifier and perform it!